# Can I use ng-repeat 2 times inside an element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am not able to show the elements from arrays previewSubs and preeviewGrades in each row like:

```
Subject    Grade
Maths       A
Maths       B
Maths       C
```

I tried putting the ng-repeat property on  element but since I can only use one ng-repeat per element (tr), I can show either subjects or grades but not both.

The below code repeats horizontally, I want it to repeat vertically downwards like the table above.

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="psubs in previewSubs">{{psubs}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="pgrades in previewGrades">{{pgrades}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="psubs in previewSubs">
            <td>{{ psubs }}</td>
            <td>{{ previewGrades[$index] }}</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: $index - I always forget it :(

Comment: @user2714639: another solution is merging 2 arrays into 1 array with each item being `{ psubs, pgrades }`. You cannot use ng-repeat 2 times like you describe in your question